# Jackson deserializing bounded types

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have a `List<Response<? extends Data>>` that I serialize into a file using Jackson.

How can I deserialize it ? all I can get is just `List.class` which isn't good enough for me.

If more code is necessary for this question, please let me know.

Comment: The serialize API you used, does it not provide a deserialize API too?

Comment: It does, but I'm not sure how to deserialize bounded types dynamically

Comment: You will have to cast it to the object that was serialized, in your case List<Response<? extends Data>>

Comment: But it won't take non concrete types

Comment: Then cast it to the List<Response<Data>>

Comment: `ClassCastException. java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to Response`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `TypeReference` object to deserialize generic types.  With the `TypeReference` object you can describe the type you want to deserialize.

```
mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Response<? extends Data>>>() {});
```

> This generic abstract class is used for obtaining full generics type information by sub-classing;

Comment: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of Data, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at ...`